# How to run a WebView in the background on Android?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I need to keep a WebView open in the background of my Android app so that I can move between pages and execute javascript. I need to be able to change activities without affecting the WebView. Occasionally I will bring it to the front but otherwise I need to maintain the same session without ever showing it. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using an activity that have your web view and show your screens as fragments